How can enter a new buy or sell order in MQL4, when the last closed trade SL was hit?
Here is a section first buy and sell code and optional code for new reentries.
I'm trying to figure this out for a while now. I've not been able to get through with it.
I tried to loop through the recently closed trade and if it's a sell order and it's stoploss was hit, a new sell trade should trigger immediately.
   if(totalTrades == 0 && (Use_Trend_Filter==No))
     {

      BE_updated = False;
      double Spread = MarketInfo(Symbol(), MODE_SPREAD);

      // FIRST TYPE OF ENTRY WITHOUT TREND FILTER |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

      if(isNewBar() && CheckTime(Start_Time,End_Time))
        {
         if(S_2 > 0 && S_2 != EMPTY_VALUE && B_1 > 0 && B_1 != EMPTY_VALUE)
           {
            if(Spread<MaxSpread && (Trade_Mode == BUY_ONLY || Trade_Mode == BOTH_TRADES))
              {
               isValidBuyTrend = true;
               //We Quickly Check to Close the Sell Trades Before Opening The New Buy
               for(int i=0; i<OrdersTotal(); i++)
                 {
                  if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES)==false)
                     break;
                  if(OrderMagicNumber()!=InpMagicNumber || OrderSymbol()!=Symbol())
                     continue;
                  //--- check order type is a sell
                  if(OrderType()==OP_SELL)
                    {
                     if(isValidBuyTrend)
                       {
                        if(!OrderClose(OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),Ask,(int)MaxSlippage,White))
                           Print("OrderClose error ",GetLastError());
                       }
                     break;
                    }
                  isValidBuyTrend = false;
                 }
               // buy
               OpenOrder(ORDER_TYPE_BUY, Ask, TP_ATR, SL_ATR);
               coutn=1;
              }
            if(Spread>MaxSpread)
              {
               Print("No trade open! Max spread reached! : ",Spread);
              }
           }

         if(B_2 > 0 && B_2 != EMPTY_VALUE && S_1 > 0 && S_1 != EMPTY_VALUE)
           {
            if(Spread<MaxSpread && (Trade_Mode == SELL_ONLY || Trade_Mode == BOTH_TRADES))
              {
               isValidSellTrend = true;
               //We Quickly Check to Close the Buy Trades Before Opening The New Sell
               for(int i=0; i<OrdersTotal(); i++)
                 {
                  if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES)==false)
                     break;
                  if(OrderMagicNumber()!=InpMagicNumber || OrderSymbol()!=Symbol())
                     continue;
                  //--- check order type is a buy
                  if(OrderType()==OP_BUY)
                    {
                     if(isValidSellTrend)
                       {
                        if(!OrderClose(OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),Bid,(int)MaxSlippage,White))
                           Print("OrderClose error ",GetLastError());
                       }
                     break;
                    }
                  isValidSellTrend = false;
                 }
               //sell
               OpenOrder(ORDER_TYPE_SELL, Bid, TP_ATR, SL_ATR);
               count=1;
              }
            if(Spread>MaxSpread)
              {
               Print("No trade open! Max spread reached! : ",Spread);
              }
           }
        }

      return;
     }



   if((B_1 > 0 && B_1 != EMPTY_VALUE) && (Use_Trend_Filter==No)&& (isAnyTradeActive()==0))
     {

      BE_updated = False;
      double Spread = MarketInfo(Symbol(), MODE_SPREAD);

      // OPTION B(1) FOR BUY COVER TRADE |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

      if(isNewBar() && CheckTime(Start_Time,End_Time))
        {
         if(Spread<MaxSpread && (Trade_Mode == BUY_ONLY || Trade_Mode == BOTH_TRADES))
           {
            // Loop through all recently closed positions
            for(int i = OrdersHistoryTotal() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
              {
               if(OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_HISTORY))
                 {
                  // Check if it's a sell order and its stoploss was hit
                  if(OrderType() == OP_BUY && OrderStopLoss() > 0 && OrderStopLoss() <= OrderClosePrice())
                    {
                     // Place sell trade again
                     int ticket = OpenOrder(ORDER_TYPE_BUY, Ask, TP_ATR, SL_ATR);
                     // Check for errors
                     if(ticket < 0)
                       {
                        Print("Error placing sell cover order: ", GetLastError());
                       }
                     else
                       {
                        Print("New sell order placed successfully at price: ", Ask);
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }

           }
        }

      return;
     }


   if((S_1 > 0 && S_1 != EMPTY_VALUE) && (Use_Trend_Filter==No)&& (isAnyTradeActive()==0))
     {

      BE_updated = False;
      double Spread = MarketInfo(Symbol(), MODE_SPREAD);

      // OPTION B(2) FOR SELL COVER TRADE |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

      if(isNewBar() && CheckTime(Start_Time,End_Time))
        {
         if(Spread<MaxSpread && (Trade_Mode == SELL_ONLY || Trade_Mode == BOTH_TRADES))
           {
            // Loop through all recently closed positions
            for(int i = OrdersHistoryTotal() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
              {
               if(OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_HISTORY))
                 {
                  // Check if it's a sell order and its stoploss was hit
                  if(OrderType() == OP_SELL && OrderStopLoss() > 0 && OrderStopLoss() >= OrderClosePrice())
                    {
                     // Place sell trade again
                     int ticket = OpenOrder(ORDER_TYPE_SELL, Bid, TP_ATR, SL_ATR);
                     // Check for errors
                     if(ticket < 0)
                       {
                        Print("Error placing sell cover order: ", GetLastError());
                       }
                     else
                       {
                        Print("New sell order placed successfully at price: ", Bid);
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }

           }
        }

      return;
     }

Thanks.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
